# Make a column vanish / package parcolumns

Tags: htlatex, parcolumns

I wrote a report in German and English language. It has two columns, German on the left, English on the right side.

Now, I need to produce a word file, but only including the german text. I've got this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\newcommand\PC[2]{\parcolumns[distance=2em]{2}%
\colchunk[1]{\selectlanguage{ngerman}#1}%
\colchunk[2]{\selectlanguage{english}#2}% \sffamily ?
 \colplacechunks\addvspace{0.3\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\PC{Text auf Deutsch.}{Text in English.}

\end{document}
```

Maybe somebody has a solution how to redefine the command `\PC`, so that the english text does not print out. Well, inserting `\color{white}` is not a solution, because the english text still would be compiled and be part of the PDF.

If I could prevent pdfLaTeX from processing the english text, I'd try to produce a html file using htlatex.

Comment: Do you want to keep the two-column output, or does a single `\textwidth`-wide column output suffice?

Comment: @Werner \textwidth would be sufficient, the solution of  jarauh works. If there were drawbacks, post a better solution, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to show only one of the two languages, you don't need to have two columns.  So how about `\newcommand\PC[2]{{\selectlanguage{ngerman}#1}}`?  That would, of course, also changes linebreaks, etc.